# How to import all provided Wildfly libraries in my maven project?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Is there a way to translate this human language in an xml codeblock that `Maven` will happily understand?

> Hey Maven, look you are a great dependency management system. I am working on a JavaEE project which is intended to be deployed on Wildfly 10.1.0. Please put all Libraries that are specified in Wildflys parent BOM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wildfly/wildfly-parent/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-parent-10.1.0.Final.pom on the compiletime classpath and consider them as provided by Wildfly at runtime. And please dont bother me to list every single referenced artifact in the dependencies section of the projects pom file. Thank you Maven, you are so cool.

To clarify:
As far as I understand, importing the bom file in the dependencyManagement section of my pom file will only spare me to specify the Version Number of every single artifact, but I will still have to declare every artifactID and groupID.

This is indeed discussed here [How to use BOM file with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven)
But in this answer is also stated:

> Then you do not have to specify the version attribute of a dependency.

I would prefer to declare only that I am using wildfly and then be able to use all client libraries without declaring any other dependencies.

But I must admit, I have the feeling to miss something obvious. There should be an easy way to do this.

Comment: You could check stackoverflow.com ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635374/how-to-use-jars-from-wildfly-correctly-in-maven  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use BOM file with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I think it is not a duplicate. The answer above only explains how to spare the declaration of version numbers, not the artifactID itself.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Typically, I only import such artifacts as I need. If you want everything, I would suggest the javaee 7 pom http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/essential_maven_pom_for_javaee or the wildfly spec api pom https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wildfly/wildfly-spec-api/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-spec-api-10.1.0.Final.pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want everything in a another `pom` to be set as a dependency and as provided you can specify that in your pom. A *minimal* pom for wildfly 10.1.0.Final that includes everything seems to be as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>wft</groupId>
    <artifactId>wft</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>wft</name>
    <description>wft</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But I would still recommend doing it the way that wildfly does it themselves, which is to put the `BOM` in the `depencency management` section and declare artifacts as you need them. Why? I don't know other than it's cleaner to read and maybe easier for maven/java to compile and build.

Comment: Thank you Karl, the wildfly-spec-api atrifact was the part that I was missing. This community here is really awsome.