# What is the correct way to download and use Wildfly Jars in a Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, pom.xml

I have Multi Module Maven Project and in the parent `pom.xml` I am importing Wildfly dependency like below -

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
      <version>21.0.2.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to run `mvn install` the sub modules start failing with compilation errors -

```
package javax.servlet.http does not exist
package org.apache.commons.beanutils does not exist
package javax.xml.ws does not exist
package javax.mail does not exist
package javax.mail.internet does not exist
```

Note: I have not mentioned any dependencies in the child `pom.xml`.

If we check the Wildfly Server zip all these jars are present under the modules directory, so probably they should get downloaded via maven as well.

I read other posts also on StackOverflow like [How to use jars from Wildfly correctly in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635374/how-to-use-jars-from-wildfly-correctly-in-maven) , but it didn't help much.

Please let me know if I am missing something or doing things wrongly.

Comment: Importing the BOM doesn’t add any dependencies - it just adds what is essentially a `dependencyManagent` block. You need to add the dependencies themselves somewhere.

Comment: The specific dependencies you mention should be added as a `provided` scope as the web server will provide its versions at run time. It’s actually an error to include Javax dependencies in your war.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I want to use the dependencies only during build time and I am not going to create an uber jar/war.

Comment: Also, if you provide an example on how I need to use the dependency in the sub module ```pom.xml``` so that it downloads all the related jar and doesn't error out during compilation.

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad You only need to reference your dependencies without their `<version>` tag, because they are alredy set inside the parent pom.

Comment: Also, don't use the parent POM to load dependencies. Not all those dependencies should be used in your application. It's better to use the the [bom](https://github.com/wildfly/boms) or the Jakarta EE BOM.